# Transacting via Spring with Activemq

Tags: java, spring, maven, activemq-classic, spring-transactions

like the title mentions i have to transact a camel session via spring with the active mq component. 
with this i had some difficulties finding the right context to use, i cant use the javaapplication context since it doesnt work with the spring versions anymore (3.0.0.3m or whatever doesnt exist anymore) and i cant use the  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext since it doesnt find the PlatformTransactionManager

```
    package mypack;
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.Endpoint;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.swing.Spring;

import org.apache.activemq.camel.component.*;
import org.apache.camel.converter.jaxb.JaxbDataFormat;
import org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.BindyType;
import org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.config.java.context.JavaConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

public class Myclass {


    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
            CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context2 = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring.xml");
            PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager = (PlatformTransactionManager) context2.getBean("jmsTransactionManager");
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) context2.getBean("jmsConnectionFactory");
            JmsComponent component = JmsComponent.jmsComponentTransacted(connectionFactory, transactionManager);
            context.addComponent("activemq", component);
            context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

                    public void configure(){

                            from("mock:quote").transacted().to("mock:class");
                    }
            });
            context.start();
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            context.stop();
    }

}
```

I deleted my route partially for this post since it is not the issue here..
thats the error i get:

```
2015-09-14 16:56:19,625 [main           ] INFO  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@246ae04d: startup date [Mon Sep 14 16:56:19 CEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-09-14 16:56:19,665 [main           ] INFO  XBeanXmlBeanDefinitionReader   - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [Spring.xml]
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.15.3 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.management.ManagedManagementStrategy - JMX is enabled
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter - Loaded 186 type converters
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.15.3 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutting down
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.15.3 (CamelContext: camel-1) uptime 0.247 seconds
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.15.3 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutdown in 0.003 seconds
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> Transacted[] <<< in route: Route(route1)[[From[mock:quote]] -> [... because of No bean could be found in the registry of type: PlatformTransactionManager
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1028)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:185)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:841)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:2911)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:2634)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:167)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2483)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2479)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2502)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:2479)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:2448)
    at mypack.Myclass.main(Myclass.java:42)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: No bean could be found in the registry of type: PlatformTransactionManager
    at org.apache.camel.model.TransactedDefinition.doResolvePolicy(TransactedDefinition.java:231)
    at org.apache.camel.model.TransactedDefinition.resolvePolicy(TransactedDefinition.java:165)
    at org.apache.camel.model.TransactedDefinition.createProcessor(TransactedDefinition.java:142)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:505)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:217)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1025)
    ... 12 more
```

And of course my Spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean id="poolConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory">
            <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="jmsTransactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
            <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
            <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
            <property name="connectionFactory" ref="poolConnectionFactory" />
            <property name="transacted" value="true" />
            <property name="transactionManager" ref="jmsTransactionManager" />
    </bean>
```

So my question is how to fix it, can i just use another context?(just ApplicatonContext didnt work fyi) or do i have to add someting in the spring.xml? all dependencies that i need till now are there and are the newest version (4.2.1.RELEASE),  soo any ideas guys? all help is welcome :)

Comment: You have Camel and you have spring and they know nothing about each other... Make camel aware of the fact that you are using Spring and that it needs t use the context to lookup beans, there currently isn't a connection.

Comment: and how do i add the connection if not via the context? I tried the AppConfig.class, but since it doesnt work with the other spring frameworks anymore....

Comment: You aren't adding any connection. The only thing that connects them is the fact that they are imported in a single class. Apache Camel is blissfully unaware of Spring in your case. I suggest a read of the Spring integration chapter of Camel.

Comment: But i dont know how to connect them.. i cant do it with the appconfig class, i cant mage my class a component (which i wouldnt do anyway since i want to integrate spring to camel, not the other way around ) and i didnt find anything anywhere which would help me, at all..

Comment: i connected them like this:CamelContext context = new SpringCamelContext(context2);
it kinda works...  but not really, it doesnt give me an error if the fie isnt there :/ not even with fileName..